# Generate public addresses (NBitcoin)

Tags: blockchain.info, c#, nbitcoin

I'm trying to generate a public address and for that, I have the code:

```
var key = new Key();
var wif = key.GetWif(Network.Main);

Console.WriteLine($"WIF: {wif}");

var secret = new BitcoinSecret(key, Network.Main);
Console.WriteLine($"Private Key: {secret.ToWif()}");
Console.WriteLine($"Public Address (Legacy): {secret.GetAddress(ScriptPubKeyType.Legacy)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Public Address (Segwit): {secret.GetAddress(ScriptPubKeyType.Segwit)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Public Address (SegwitP2SH): {secret.GetAddress(ScriptPubKeyType.SegwitP2SH)}");
```

When I pick the WIF and import it to Blockchain.com (for example), I only get the Legacy public address. Can the same private key sign Segwit and SegwitP2SH transactions?
How can I import a private key and get the Segwit and SegwitP2SH public addresses?

My knowledge about how this works is limited and I'm trying to learn...

Answer (score 1):

Question was [posted & answered on the NBitcoin repo](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin/issues/1034), so copying my answers here for the benefit of SE members:

> This is a Blockchain.com-specific UX issue... They technically could generate a Segwit address, but they default to `P2PKH` (legacy) at the moment.
>
> `WIF` is an old format that doesn't carry metadata about the kind of address that should be unwrapped from the private key, so when you import a private key `WIF` into a wallet, it's up to the wallet to decide what kind of address to give you for that private key.
>
> ps: Some wallets are "smart" and check all possible addresses (Legacy, Segwit, SegwitP2SH, ...) and then pick whichever one has a balance, so you might want to put some satoshis on the Segwit address that you create *before* importing the private key `WIF` to a wallet.

---

> Private keys can be associated with public keys that are either compressed (`33` bytes) or uncompressed (`65` bytes), and the `WIF` will be different if compressed/uncompressed. For instance, compressed public keys start with `L` or `K` on Mainnet and `c` on Testnet, whilst uncompressed public keys start with `5` on Mainnet and `9` on Testnet.
>
> You can modify your code sample above to use uncompressed public keys (the default is compressed):
>
> ```
> var key = new Key(fCompressedIn: false);
> // ...
> ```

---